# Nav bar height issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i need your help...i inserted an image in my navbar but my image fit to the navbar i need some space on top and bottom and i just want to increase the font size of the brand text. i don't know how to adjust it, i tried to put some css but nothing happen.

kindly see.

```
<div class="navbar-header">

    <a href="index.html"  class="brand"><img src="images/egtdesign-logo.png">EGT DESIGN</a>

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">

         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>

</div>        
    <!--MENU and SOCIAL MEDIA LINK-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="nav-collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav " >
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="portfolio.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> PORTFOLIO</a></li>
           <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact-form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> CONTACT</a>
           </li>

           <!--SOCIAL MEDIA -->
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook_ico.png" alt="EGT Design"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter_ico.png"></a></li>
             <li><a href="http://plus.google.com"><img src="images/google plus.png"></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login"><img src="images/Linkdin_ico.png"></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--END MENU collapse-->

</div><!--END OF CONTAINER-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using twitter bootstrap? put your css below the twitter bootstrap css so that your custom css will override it.

To put some space at the top and in the bottom of the image.

```
a.brand img{margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

and if you want to increase the font of the brand text

```
a.brand{font-size:20px;}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but my menu is not center align with the brand. how can i adjust my menu?

Comment: oh i already resolved the alignment of my menu, it just that i needed to put the alignment in collapse in order to align with the brand. thanks.

Comment: i encountered another problem, after adding a margin-left to the a.brand and aligning the menu to the brand, i noticed that my menu drops when it reaches to 768x1024(vertical for ipad). kindly help to resolve it. thanks

Comment: in order to achieve that you need media queries. When the window size meet the width of the query, adjust the image.

try this `@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {//do something}`

Comment: should i alter the @media or should i put this code inside the CSS?

Comment: you can alter the css in bootstrap but I recommend to put your custom css on other file. just override the twitter bootstrap.

Comment: i tried to put some code in @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {}but nothing happen, can your give me some samples?

Comment: sample `@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {a.brand img{width:150px; height:auto;}}`

you need to adjust the screen to see the effect